# How to test a component which is built with styled component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

I'm new to React testing and with Jest and Enzyme.
I'm trying to learn how to use a TDD approach first and due to that, I'm building my tests before starting coding. 
What I did was to create a sample app in React and I installed Enzyme dependencies and then I wrote the test:

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import AppLayout from "./AppLayout";
import { ContentLayout } from "./styles";

it("renders <AppLayout /> component", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<AppLayout />);
  expect(wrapper.find(ContentLayout)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
});
```

Then I built the component which contains a styled component called ContentLayout

```
import React from "react";
import { ContentLayout } from "./styles";

const AppLayout = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <ContentLayout>
                <h1>HELLO</h1>
            </ContentLayout>
        </>
    );
};

export default AppLayout;
```

I'm unable yo make the test pass as what I got was the next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

I would like to learn how shoulæd be the practice to test this kind of component and what rules to follow in general when I start a project from scratch with TDD in mind.

The AppLayout is called then in App.js

```
import React from "react";
import AppLayout from "./Components/AppLayout";

function App() {
    return <AppLayout />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you read the Jest docs? `.to` isn't part of their expect API: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect, you may be thinking of Chai's https://www.chaijs.com/.

Comment: I was also following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56373421/7882685 bu yes that doesn't exist I'm trying to use tohavelenght(number)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.toHaveLength(number)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber) matchers of `expect` in jestjs.

```js
expect(wrapper.find(ContentLayout)).toHaveLength(1);
```

For nested components, there are two strategies generally:

- [Shallow Rendering API](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md)

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to test a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting the behavior of child components.

This means we don't want to render the nested component(`ContentLayout`), we only test the behavior(lifecycle methods, event handlers, data fetching, condition render, etc.) of the parent component(`AppLayout`).

- [Full Rendering API (mount(...))](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md)

> Full DOM rendering is ideal for use cases where you have components that may interact with DOM APIs or need to test components that are wrapped in higher order components.